# RMagick image conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

While hacking a simple project I'm stuck with a `RMagick` problem for a day now. Since I am very new to `RMagick` need suggestions on this.

I am trying to scan a user uploaded image and try to snap/select the image to specific region where actual content is. But there is a chance that user can take image with phone or other device and end up adding much noise to image.

Example [image](https://ibb.co/J77tjfR) uploaded from user looks like this.

I tried to convert the image to a `greyscale` like bellow

```
 img.quantize(2, GRAYColorspace, false)
```

But which has so much of noise when converted ([image](https://ibb.co/gtDLjmN)). Could any one suggest how can I select only the section/rectangle which contains actual information from the uploaded image?

Bellow are the methods I'm trying to get my hands dirt with.

- get_pixels
- find_similar_region
- adaptive_threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick command line, you can use -negate (invert colors) and -lat (local area threshold) to convert this to binary (black/white), which might be more what you want. There should be equivalent commands in RMagick.

Input:
[image]

```
convert t2.jpg -negate -lat 20x20+10% -negate result.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Note, there are a few dark spots in the resulting image above. You need to filter those using -connected-components before you can trim the image to the black box.

```
convert t2.jpg -negate -lat 20x20+10% -negate -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=10 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
-bordercolor white -border 1x1 \
-fuzz 15% -trim +repage \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to crop the image to actual content. i,e to form rectangle. How can I crop?

Comment: See my addition in my post.